# Using fake timestamps to create partitions on Google BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Google BigQuery (BQ) allows you to create a partition using `timestamp` or `date` types only.

99% of my data has a very clear selector, idClient. I've created to my customer's views with a predicate like `idClient = code` so the privacy is guaranteed.

The problem with this strategy is that there are customers with 5M rows and others with 200K and as `BQ` does not have indexes, they are always processing data from each other (and the costs are rising).

I am intending to create a `timestamp` field where each customer will have a different `timestamp` that will be repeated for every Insert in every customer sensitive table and thus I can query by `timestamp` by fixing it as it would be with a standard ID.

Does this make any sense? If BQ was an indexed database I'd be concerned about skewed data but as it is always full table scan, I think I'd have only benefits and no downsides.

Comment: What is your workload? Depending on your use-case you might be better off with an actual database.

Comment: Today  ~80M rows but as a startup we always dream big. Latency for small queries aside, BQ is better in most cases in our analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for your problem is to add Cluster field to your table which is equivalent to an Index in other databases

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables) provides the basic on how to use cluster field

> Clustering can improve the performance of certain types of queries such as queries that use filter clauses and queries that aggregate data. When data is written to a clustered table by a query job or a load job, BigQuery sorts the data using the values in the clustering columns

Note: When using cluster field BigQuert dryRun doesn't show the cost improvement which can only be seen post-execution

Comment: I had already seen this but I thought that I would have to partition the table anyway and what you are saying is that a null partition with cluster will solve the case. Two questions please: 1) Cluster columns + null partition will completely avoid miss-reading data? 2) Wouldn't be even better to partition and cluster the columns?

Comment: Yes 2 is the correct solution for you. someone edit my original answer which is not ok and add the null comments :(. Hope you find this answer the right one so you can vote and accept it.

Comment: Hello Tamir. Here is a problem that I am probably going to face. When I stream data,  I can only stream between (today -356 and today + 183). At the beginning my reference "id" was 2000/01/01:00:00 but now I put my reference to 183 days in the future. A year and half from now, my partitions will be automatically excluded and/or I won't be able to stream data to it anymore? The whole thing sounds to me a little bit weird, it is a very important feature in terms of cost/performance and google seems to not understand this

Comment: Hi @JLCDev Partition should be a date filed and you can simply use the insert date as it's value. Cluster field should be `idClient` so both fields now store meaningful data. You can use both or only 1 per your use case in the query to get a maximum saving of cost. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56076318/clustering-in-bigquery-using-create-table/56078941#56078941) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55606101/how-does-bigquery-table-works-with-partition-and-cluster-field/55609635#55609635) for some more details

Comment: ok. Understood. Last question. Do you know I can't create stream to a partition with any timestamp but only with D-365 and D+183? (being D= today). My concern is that my partitions would not be functional one year and a half from now and I would not be able to continue streaming to it. I am willing to take the risk and bet on google improving its partition features, I'd like just to know if I have to countdown until there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi JLCDev that's a question you need to ask BigQuery team they have defiantly step up in past year with improving many of the limitations but again I can't say.

Comment: Just a quick work around for you in case you will need it, you can also aggregate partition by month and year so technically you will be able to create an archive table with aggregate information per month and another non partition field with the excat date. You can than join between short and long term data where needed. You can always open another question to get more details on such workarounds.